# Running docker container : iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: docker, port, iptables

I'm trying to run a container but I get the following issue :

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container b005715c40ea7d5821b15c44f5b7f902d4b39da7c83468f3e5d7c042e5fe3fbd: iptables failed: iptables --wait -t filter -A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -d 172.17.0.43 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
 (exit status 1)
```

Here is the command I use :

```bash
docker run -d -p 10080:80 -v /srv/http/website/data:/srv/http/www/data -v /srv/http/website/logs:/srv/http/www/logs myimage
```

Isn't opening port 80 on my server enough? Is there something I missed with docker interface?
I use iptables with a script like this :

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# reset :
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t filter -X

# Block all :
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP

# Authorize already established connections :
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Authorize backloop :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Authorize ssh :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize HTTP :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize HTTPS :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize DNS :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# Ping :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Authorize FTP :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT

# # Authorize NTP :
# iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize IRC :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6667 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 6667 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize port 10000 (for Node.JS server) :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize port 631 (Cups server) :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT

# Authorize port 9418 (git) :
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9418 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9418 -j ACCEPT
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: I answered this question before [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70095863/10450803)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I believe the issue is within these lines:

iptables -t filter -F

iptables -t filter -X

which indeeds clear all chains. One possible solution is to launch the docker daemon *after* the iptables setup script. Otherwise you will need to explicitly removes chains you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem : I just restarted the docker daemon and now everything works fine!

Comment: Be careful when you run this commands. If you run it on remote server it will cause to terminate your ssh session also.

Answer (score 119):

I faced the same problem in a docker-compose setup.

**1. Clear all chains:**

```
sudo iptables -t filter -F
sudo iptables -t filter -X
```

**2. Then restart Docker Service:**

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: for me `systemctl restart docker` without flushing `iptables` worked just fine!

Comment: Restarting the docker daemon worked for me too, thanks! I remember that I had to clear all iptables tables a couple of days ago and it also cleared the tables installed by docker.

Comment: WARNING - Do not do this over SSH as this will clear all your iptables rules and you will be unable to connect back to the server.

Answer (score 60):

Faced the same issue on RHEL 7. Restarting docker service worked for me without a need to flush any `iptable` rules.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: I strongly suggest anyone running into this issue checks out this solution. It saved me a bunch of time.

Comment: Yes it is just a workaround. Not sure what needs to be done, to avoid it.

Answer (score 20):

I get same problem, after installing firewalld.

I fix it by:

```
service firewalld stop
service docker restart
```

Comment: This worked for me, but don't know if there are any major security risks for stoping firewalld.

Comment: This also worked for me, but after restarting docker, I turned the firewall back on, and then started the container. The error message went away at that point.

Answer (score 7):

The error may happen because it is trying to affect the iptables "DOCKER" filter chain, but is not there.

The option --iptables=false prevents docker from changing the iptables configuration.

(Source: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/#communicating-to-the-outside-world)

If you opt for fixing the iptables docker filter chain, here's how to.

You can actually edit the iptables and add it, so that it looks like in the example here [Docker: How to re-create dockers additional iptables rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917941/docker-how-to-re-create-dockers-additional-iptables-rules)

Like this

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Add the ":DOCKER" lines

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [144:8072]
:INPUT ACCEPT [87:5208]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [118:8055]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [118:8055]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
... your previous rules here ...
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5781:5099614]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
... your previous rules here ...
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Restart... e.g.

```
service iptables restart
```

A good "further read" link where it is well explained

https://medium.com/@ebuschini/iptables-and-docker-95e2496f0b45

Answer (score 1):

In irc.freenode.net#docker you have stated that you are using Arch Linux ARM on a Raspberry Pi.

If you are not running this script as a part of a systemd service, I would strongly suggest moving to that, or making use of the existing iptables services and using their ability to save/restore the tables at the appropriate times. If you choose to move to your own services, make sure that the unit states that it is ordered `Before=docker.service`

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. before running docker start mongodb , I was testing ssh service.

below command can solve this issue for me.

```
iptables -t filter -F

iptables -t filter -X

systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes I faced the same issue and as mentioned above below commands worked for me

```
sudo iptables -t filter -F


sudo iptables -t filter -X


systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: You should upvote the answer that worked for you instead of duplicating it.

Answer (score -2):

I can confirm that this problem is caused by iptables or firewalld because before my containers stopped I edited my firewall's rules.

```
iptables -t filter -X
iptables -t filter -F
```

Comment: You should upvote the answer that worked for you instead of duplicating it.