# iptables: No chain/target/match error (with docker network create)

Tags: docker, networking, iptables

When creating a network (`docker network create -d bridge my-nw`), I obtained this error in response:

> Error response from daemon: Failed to Setup IP tables: Unable to enable SKIP DNAT rule:  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -I DOCKER -i br-bedba04c7349 -j RETURN: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

What do I need to do to go around? Docker or IP Table modifications?

Answer (score 90):

Something has deleted the docker iptables entries. Docker will recreate them if you restart it (`systemctl restart docker`). You'll want to disable anything else that manages iptables to prevent this from happening in the future.

Comment: This command restarts the whole docker but you can just restart docker.socket

Comment: @behrad Restarting the socket restarts the docker daemon, it's a dependency for running the engine. The code to reset the firewall settings is part of the engine startup.

Comment: That something in my case turned out to be temporarily disabling firewalld , but same as others restarting the docker service `systemctl restart docker` makes it work again

Answer (score 25):

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.socket
```

Comment: indeed that fixes the issue, but that would even better if one could explain the root cause.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110146/can-anyone-explain-docker-sock 
-@BaptisteMille-Mathias

Comment: This will result in the docker engine being restarted. See the output of `systemctl cat docker | grep docker.socket` to see the dependency.

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when you accidently flush all your chains and tables, for example using `iptables --flush`. Simply restart your docker daemon as mentioned by BMitch