# Docker-compose: must disable firewall and restart docker service when docker-compuse up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

I start learning how to use Docker and docker-compose and everytime I reboot my computer, I got this message when I do a docker-compose up:

> Creating network "dockerlemp_default" with the default driver
>
> ERROR: Failed to program FILTER chain: iptables failed: iptables --wait -I FORWARD -o br-74bd0d3628e8 -j DOCKER: iptables v1.6.1: Couldn't load target `DOCKER':No such file or directory
>
> Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Once the firewall disabled by doing the command `sudo ufw disable` and once the docker service restarted by the command `systemctl restart docker`, I can up my docker-compose normally.
But I have to do it everytime I reboot.

Can someone explain me what the issue is with the iptables and how to fix this definitely ?
Thank you very much.

FYI, here is my setup:

> Lenovo Ideapad 510S-08ISH - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6400 CPU @ 2.70GHz
>
> Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Bionic (window manager i3wm)
>
> Docker 18.09.7
>
> docker-compose 1.17.1

Comment: Drop you iptables with #iptables -F , then restart docker #/etc/init.d/docker restart. Ensure that your docker starts first that your iptables on  /etc/rc*.d/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last Docker versions do manipulate with `iptables`'s rules in enough correct manner, even on Debian/Ubuntu (you don't use `selinux`, do you?). So this error means that some libs/configs are broken. Try the following steps:

1. Check if chain `DOCKER` presents in `iptables`'s rules (`iptables --list-rules | grep '\-N\ DOCKER'`). If it doesn't, then you can add the command `iptables -N DOCKER` to `if-pre-up` script (`/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables`). It's just workaround, the better solution is to reinstall `iptables` and/or `docker` The latter depends on how you installed it. Maybe it makes sense to change the method (`apt-get install docker.io` instead `wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh` and vise versa). In that case don't forget to uninstall Docker first.
2. If `DOCKER` chain presents, then check if you have `iptables-restore` command in `if-pre-up` script (usually `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables`). If yes, then try to re-create the source file for `iptables-restore` or even temprorary disable `iptables-restore`.
3. Check your Docker configs (`/etc/docker/daemon.json` and `/etc/default/docker`). Perhaps some application has written some unwanted options there.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error when I used `sudo docker-compose`, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51046151/18632336):

```
sudo iptables -t filter -F

sudo iptables -t filter -X

systemctl restart docker
```

and it totally worked.