# Can't understand docker iptables rule

Tags: docker

When using docker, we start with a image. And I created a container with docker.

```
docker run --name register -d -p 1180:5000 registry
```

iptables rules can be listed by running iptables-save:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Oct 16 14:01:03 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [129:14002]
:INPUT ACCEPT [129:14002]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [25:1792]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [25:1792]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1180 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:5000
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Oct 16 14:01:03 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Oct 16 14:01:03 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2721358:1990060388]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2726902:1992988803]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Oct 16 14:01:03 2017
```

I don't understand this rule.

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: This is probably a question for https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best guess is that rule is to fix an edge case when you have the iptables `POSTROUTING` table defaulting to DENY any packets that don't match a rule, this allows connections from the container to itself on a mapped port through.  In normal operation the rules do nothing functional.

I think this is the [pull request (#7003)](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/7003) that added the MASQ rule but there's no documentation as to why it was added. The commit was labeled ["Create tests for pkg/iptables"](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/7003/commits/0da92633b4161ed1f8babe5ec4a9fe98257d34b5). The work was generally around fixing Docker on distro's that have default DENY tables.

There is a suggestion in [issue #12632](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12632) that the rule won't be touched unless the userland port mapping proxy is turned off.

Comment: Seems more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is illustrated in "[Bind container ports to the host](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/)"

> By default Docker containers can make connections to the outside world, but the outside world cannot connect to containers. Each outgoing connection will appear to originate from one of the host machine’s own IP addresses thanks to an iptables masquerading rule on the host machine that the Docker server creates when it starts:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -L -n

...
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0
...
```

> The Docker server creates a masquerade rule that lets containers connect to IP addresses in the outside world.

You can see [in this thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-and-iptables-configuration-startup/904) what happens when those rules are *not* generated. (they [need to be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25917941/6309))

You can study those same options in "[Build your own bridge](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/build-bridges/)".

Comment: The rule in question is a little different though, the standard MASQUERADE for outbound connections is the rule above in ops output.  This rule is specifically about the container connecting to itself, on the target port of a port mapping. I'm not sure why a MASQ rule is used there, unless it wants to change the source IP of those connections. Apparently it's only hit when [you turn the userland proxy off](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12632)

Comment: @Matt Thank you for referencing the [moby issue 33726](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33726). I am not sure either.

Comment: @Matt OK, I'll follow it and see if there are any new answer there.

Comment: I actually think that rule is useless, even though it gets hit.  I believe MASQ will choose the outbound interfaces IP as the new source address, which is already the source address.